# Split Spring configuration by modules

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, configuration

I'm trying to split workable spring application into logically separated modules. Let's simplify condition and imagine we have only one module BusinessAppConf (this one for user WEB interaction purposes only) and the main Application Context Initializer.

This is a workable scheme but with using static methods to register config classes related to the business module.

The WebApplicationInitializer (web.xml is was replaced by the implementation of this interface)

```
public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    @Autowired
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = getContext();
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic mainDispatcher =
                container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(context));
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic businessDispatcher =
                container.addServlet("businessDispatcher", BusinessAppConfig.createDispatcherServlet(context));
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic ppaDispatcher =
                container.addServlet("ppaDispatcher", PpaAppConfig.createDispatcherServlet(context));

        initDispatcher(mainDispatcher, 1, "/");
        initDispatcher(businessDispatcher, 2, "/business");
        initDispatcher(businessDispatcher, 3, "/ppa");
    }

    private void initDispatcher(ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher, int loadOnStartUp, String mapping) {
        if (dispatcher == null) {
            System.out.println("Servlet" + dispatcher.getName() + " is already added");
        } else {
            dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(loadOnStartUp);
            dispatcher.addMapping(mapping);
        }
    }

    public AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext getContext() {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.register(MvcConfiguration.class);
        return context;
    }

    @Bean(name = "propertyConfigurer")
    public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer getPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        placeholderConfigurer.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("common.properties"));
        placeholderConfigurer.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("amazon.S3Storage.properties"));
        placeholderConfigurer.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("local.storage.properties"));
        placeholderConfigurer.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("log4j.properties"));
        placeholderConfigurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
        return placeholderConfigurer;
    }
}
```

Business Config module with static methods:

BusinessAppConfig class file

```
@Configuration
public class BusinessAppConfig {

    public static Servlet createDispatcherServlet(AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context) {
        context.register(BusinessMvcConfig.class);
        return new DispatcherServlet(context);
    }
}
```

and

BusinessMvcConfig class config

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"business"})
@EnableWebMvc
public class BusinessMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
    public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(500000000L);
        return multipartResolver;
    }
}
```

BusinessHibernateConfig.class

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
//@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"business.dao", "business.model", "ppa.dao", "ppa.model"})
@PropertySource("classpath:rdbmsDev.properties")
public class BusinessHibernateConfig {

@Autowired
private Environment env;

@Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws NamingException, IOException {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

    Properties createStrategy = new Properties();
    createStrategy.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));

    emf.setJpaProperties(createStrategy);
    emf.setPackagesToScan("business");
    emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(getJpaVendorAdapter());
    BasicDataSource dataSource = getDataSource();
    emf.setDataSource(dataSource);

    return emf;
}

@Bean
public DatabasePopulator createDatabasePopulator(BasicDataSource dataSource) {
    ResourceDatabasePopulator databasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
    databasePopulator.setContinueOnError(false);
    databasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("create.sql"));
    DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(databasePopulator, dataSource);
    return databasePopulator;
}

private JpaVendorAdapter getJpaVendorAdapter() {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    jpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
    jpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
    jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform(env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    return jpaVendorAdapter;
}

@Bean
public BasicDataSource getDataSource() {
    BasicDataSource basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    basicDataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
    basicDataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.username"));
    basicDataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));
    basicDataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
    basicDataSource.setInitialSize(Ints.tryParse(env.getProperty("connection.init_size")));
    basicDataSource.setMaxIdle(Ints.tryParse(env.getProperty("connection.pool_size")));
    return basicDataSource;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
}
```

}

I don't like that static methods are being used here. It seems incorrect implementations. So, the question is next are these files have been configured properly? If no how it should be configured like?

Comment: The full project is here https://github.com/BessonovEvgeniy/Octava

Answer (score 0):

Use `AbstractContextLoaderInitializer` instead of `WebApplicationInitializer` because

- it registers a `ContextLoaderListener` for you
- you can use your code for registering dispatcher servlet o onStartu method
- you can override `createRootApplicationContext` method  to create your root application Context that contains business services and it will be provided to the `ContextLoaderListener` in your case is `BusinessAppConfig`

Comment: Hi, thanx for your recommendation. I've tried this approach and I have some misunderstanding how it should be used. Do you have an example of such implementation? How to use AbstractContextLoaderInitializer If I need: 1) to add new Servlet for each separate module (in our case it's an only Business module) and 2) to register all related to a Business module configured classes (BusinessHibernateConf.class, BusinessMvcConfig.class) in one particular place?